# Arcgis javascript - pan and zoom simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I'm using my android device to test the arcgis javascript API 's touch support. I noticed that by default, I cannot pan and zoom the map at the same time, like google maps. Am I missing something? A property, map option, some custom code to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not missing something.  The ESRI javascript API does not support panning and zooming at the same time with touch gestures.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out a long time ago. Still not supported, too bad.